# "%" sign in a matplotlib Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, plot, legend

Is there any way that I can print a % sign in a plot on python using matplotlib in a Text object or inside a Legend?

This basic example, without a raw percent sign, behaves as expected:

```
plt.figure()
TotEne,= plt.plot_date(time, ETTG['output'], 'b-', label='Total Energy')
UsEne,= plt.plot_date(time, EUUG['output'], 'r-',label='Used Energy')
plt.ylabel('kWh')
plt.text('2015-12-15',25000,'Energy Losses=%.2f'%pEW, clip_on=True)
plt.legend(handles=[TotEne,UsEne])   
plt.show()
```

In that case the text says "Energy Losses = ". But I wonder if there is a possible way to display "Energy Losses=%" or, "%Energy Losses=".

When I try to do that, it raises a TypeError. I just want to literally display the "%" character. So doing this:

```
plt.figure()
TotEne,= plt.plot_date(time, ETTG['output'], 'b-', label='Total Energy')
UsEne,= plt.plot_date(time, EUUG['output'], 'r-',label='Used Energy')
plt.ylabel('kWh')
plt.text('2015-12-15',25000,'%Energy Losses=%.2f'%pEW, clip_on=True)
plt.legend(handles=[TotEne,UsEne])  
plt.show()
```

Raises this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-559-9d13c78a6754> in <module>()
     20 plt.ylabel('kWh')
     21 
---> 22 plt.text('2015-12-15',25000,'%Energy Losses=%.2f'%pEW, clip_on=True)
     23 
     24 plt.legend(handles=[TotEne,UsEne])

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

How do I include a literal percent sign ("%") in a matplotlib figure with an interpolated string using the `%` operator?

Answer (score 5):

To print `%` you need to "escape" it using `"%%"`. Change your code to:

```
plt.text('2015-12-15',25000,'%%Energy Losses=%.2f'%pEW, clip_on=True)
```

Comment: i would include using `"Energy Losses  = {:.2f}%".format(pEW)` as another potential solution